# React native maps get visible markers

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

On iOS when using map kit we are able to get the current annotations inside of the visible map rect. Here is a small snippet using swift

```
Array(myMap.annotations(in: myMap.visibleMapRect))
```

Is there any comparable method or callback in this library?

My basic use is to know when a user changed region (pinch to zoom etc) and to get an array of the current markers still visible.

Comment: Haven't tried it but have you taken a look at `getMarkersFrames` method? Check here - https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md

Comment: Otherwise you could try `getMapBoundaries` and manually check which of your markers are within those boundaries.

Comment: Would you have a snippet of getMarkersFrames or a sample of how I would compute getMapBoundaries to the coordinates I have in markers? The latter seems like it may be very slow. If I have 6,000 pins, and having to iterate over them 1 by 1 every time a region is set. Maybe I'm wrong

Comment: Yeah you're probably right in that case. Not ideal solution

Comment: Will try get a code snippet for you and try getMarkersFrames out

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Jono Any luck on that snippet?

Comment: Hey @mKane, this is the example from the library itself (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/example/examples/FitToCoordinates.js), I've tried it out on snack (https://snack.expo.io/@jonoh/playful-toffee) but it didn't log the markers as I assume you need a native deployment on an actual device (not through snack) to make it work. Hope it helps!

Comment: As has been said before, this will only work with iOS though.

Comment: Yes that is fine. I will run through it today. Thank you!

Comment: My pleasure! Let me know if it works :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a `getMarkersFrames` function to do that, but it is `iOS` only, and that's why I never used one in my apps.

I solved the same problem by using the RBush library to store markers: https://github.com/mourner/rbush. It allows to easily select points in the selected region. And it does it fast by using an R-tree. Example:

```
getInitialState() {
    return {
        region: {
            latitude: 37.78825,
            longitude: -122.4324,
            latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
            longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
        },
    };
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.tree = new RBush();
    fetch().then((points) => {
        // RBush expects the point to have minX, maxX, minY, maxY
        // but it could be configured.
        this.tree.load(points);
    });
}

onRegionChangeComplete(region) {
    // Get points that are inside the region.
    visibleItems = this.tree.search({
        // Provide the coordinates of the south-west, north-east corners of the region.
        minX: region.longitude - region.longitudeDelta,
        minY: region.latitude - region.latitudeDelta,
        maxX: region.longitude + region.longitudeDelta,
        maxY: region.latitude + region.latitudeDelta
    });
    this.setState({ region, visibleItems });
}

render() {
    return (
        <MapView
            region={this.state.region}
            onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete}
        />
    );
}
```

My app uses the same approach except I do initial markers loading and search in `redux` and `redux-saga`.

If you doesn't need to show that many markers, you can use simpler approach by storing points in the array. Then on each region change loop through all of the places and select those that are inside the region.

Comment: I will look into this. Im confused by the componentWillMount code. where does the fetch code come from?

Comment: @mKane That's just an example of fetching data from the server. All of the points has to be loaded to the tree after you have received them.

Comment: @mKane I already showed this in `componentWillMount`. In my example `fetch()` is a function from Fetch API, shown just as a generic example. Can you show how do you load your points, and what data your points have (latitude, longitude, something else)?

Comment: ah ok so this.tree.load is what in takes my points. Ok I understand. Let me try my code with this. Are you able to provide an example of the getMarkersFrames for iOS so I can compare?

Comment: @mKane I never tried `getMarkersFrames` because it is `iOS` only, but I have to implement both iOS and Android.

Comment: ok thanks. I am definitely looking for an example of getMarkersFrames but thank you